# Web-авторизация

Tags: веб-программирование, авторизация

Товарищи, может посоветуете хороший сервис, библиотеку, идею, собственную реализацию современной авторизации и аутентификации для сайта. Главные критерии: безопасность, разделение прав.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Авторизация ползователей через социальные сети, т.е. авторизация "в один клик". Почитайте [статью об этом](http://habrahabr.ru/post/145988/). Посмотрите API Google [OAuth 2.0 for Login](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login)

Answer (score 2):

По моему мнению самое лучшее и простое: [Безопасный метод авторизации на PHP](http://habrahabr.ru/post/13726/).

Answer (score 0):

Могу посоветовать уроки. [Создание регистрации на сайте на PHP + MySQL](http://ruseller.com/project.php?id=5) или [Простая система регистрации пользователей для Вашего сайта](http://ruseller.com/adds.php?rub=12&id=1689), а после читайте это [Управление привилегиями пользователя на основе ролей](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub_id=37&id=1444).

Answer (score 0):

А если погуглить и почитать о стандартном `AuthType` от `Apache`? Например, здесь: [Все об AuthType или авторизация в Apache](http://www.codenet.ru/webmast/apache/Apache-Access.php).

Comment: А если не Apache? Может у человека nginx или tomcat стоит. Без указаний технологий в вопросе напрашивается ответ озвученный выше пользователем под ником Deonis